# i am a kid and my parents are asking who do i want to stay with... what should i answer?

Tags: divorce

I am a kid and my parents are asking who do I want to stay with... because I think they might want to **divorce**... what should I answer? I love both of them and do not want to live separately from any of my parents. :( And I hope they actually don't. Please answer I don't want to be sad my whole life it would really help!
I am just a kid... 9 year old... please help I don't know what to do... I love my family.... lets also hope they won't actually divorce...
From Zenisha

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  I'm sorry you're going through this; unfortunately, this site only allows users over 13 years old, so we're really not able to help here.  Know that your parents both love you very much, and while sometimes things don't work out the way you would prefer, they do always work out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can’t permit users under 13 (or 16 in the EU) to participate.

Comment: oh, that's sad...

Comment: See also https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/40910/hi-i-am-under-14-and-i-wonder-why-my-parents-are-fighting-so-much/40911#40911 . How about asking for a solution that lets you split the time between them in a way that works for you and seems fair to you, including the quality of that time (e.g. weekends are better than weekdays). Think about how you spend your time with them now, and how you might carry on doing those things if they are living apart.